# How do I indent the first line of \paragraph{Title}

Tags: sections-paragraphs

When using \paragraph{}, the first line is not indented by default. How can I change the setting so the default will be indented?

Update:
Here is an example of what I want to do. I have

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Indented paragraph.
\paragraph{Paragraph Title is not indented} Blah blah...

\end{document}
```

I want to indent the *title* of this section-paragraph, same as a standard paragraph.

Comment: You give no context of your setup, so we can only assume you're using the default. In the default paragraph is inline (no line break after Title) so how does indentation even make sense in this context. If you're not using the default setup, you now know why we always ask for a minimal (but complete) example showing what you're doing and what setup you're using.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I haven't given any setup. Yes, I want to indent the Title.

Comment: Then give us some setup, I still do not understand what you're trying to do? If you just want an unnumbered headline the why noyæt use one of the starred sections?

Comment: I've updated the post. @daleif

Comment: OK, then explain why you want it to be indented? Paragraph is already adding vertical space before it, so it makes no sense to indent it as well, that just looks strange and superfluous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple with `titlesec`:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{\parindent}{*1.5}{0.75em}

\begin{document}

Blah blah... Some text. Some other text. Some more text. Some more text. Some other text. Some more text. Some more text.
Indented paragraph.
\paragraph{Paragraph Title is indented.} Blah blah... Some text. Some other text. Some more text. Some more text. Some other text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]